# Why apache server go faster after reboot?

Tags: linux, debian, apache-httpd, mysql, php

I notice a significant performance gain after a reboot of the server (Apache Debian / PHP / MariaDB Mysql).

For several weeks, the page loading time gradually increased from 50 ms to 150 ms and immediately after the reboot the server regained its performance of 50 ms.

I saw on some forums that it could come from the mysql server? Maybe things that get cached?
(The server makes a very large number of always different mysql requests)

Comment: When things get slow, what does your memory consumption and swap usage look like?  Without more info, this sounds like you're running out of memory and the system is starting to swap.

Answer (score 1):

As one elder colleague mine once taught me "only windows grown losers solve problems by rebooting servers". He was quite grumpy and old like I am getting now. Please no offense, fellow windows admins, these are his words.

Problem is hardly in the ystem (ie. OS) and probably somewhere in your application stack. Here is simple example of problem service localization algorithm by service restart and elimination (this require only common sense and have ability to restart service mid operation (in HA you often cannot)):

- What happens when your service gets slow and you restart just apache server (no-reboot)?
- What happens when your service gets slow and you restart just php-fpm server (no-reboot)? If you are not running fpm, there could be your problem?
- What happens when your service gets slow and you restart just mysql server (no-reboot)?

If the service gets fast again after restart of one of the services, that might be culprit. If you need multiple (ie two) services to restart, the problem is spread between those two.

Once you have problematic service pinned down, observe logs for errors and so on...

You are bound to find something somewhere.